# Graviton-ite disasters?

Tags: technological-development

Imagine a world in which there is a special mineral, Gravitite, which has the odd property of being able to attract gravitons, depending on how much electricity is flowing through it.

What potential disasters could result with this technology, other than the formation of a black hole?

More on Gravitite: This mineral naturally attracts gravitons, but to a weak extent. This attraction is amplified, however, if the electrical current flowing through it increases. Additionally depending on the voltage bias given to it. It can be compared to a memristor in the sense that a voltage bias on either "terminal" (electrical contacts connected to it) will either increase or decrease the resistance (in this case, amount of gravitons attracted). There is a point where the voltage is either to small or too large at a terminal, of which it repels gravitons. This hysteresis loop example (meant for modeling the memristor, but im using it for gravitite modeling) displays how it attracts and repels gravitons. As the voltage increases, eventually it first starts to repel electrons, but then suddenly it reverses and it attracts gravitons.

[image: Hysteresis Loop Model]

Comment: possibly too broad, or bordering on opinion I think, can you give us some more information? does Gravite just do this on its own, or is it activated some way (ex: applied electrical current)?

Comment: Could it also repel gravitrons if you reverse the flow? or does it just convert electricity into gravity regardless of other factors.

Comment: "attracts gravitons" - does this mean it can steals something's weight (weight, not mass)? As in, if there is a plate of gravitite below me, once it is turns on, the gravitons from the Earth that were headed for me are instead attracted to the plate. With fewer gravitons reaching me, I might start floating. Is this how you pictured it working? Either way, you should include an example of gravitite in action in your question.

Comment: Does the direction of the flow of electricity matter? If I _reverse the polarity_ does it repel gravitons? Jamming a rod of this stuff into the powerpoint would be hilariously entertaining if so.

Comment: Second question: Since time-varying magnetic fields create time-varying electric fields, will just waving a stick of this about cause it to react with the Earth's magnetic field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty large question to field, but with the basis of “potential disasters” in the question I feel it is field-able. I’m making the assumption that this is an Earth analogue and there are human analogues present. I’m also assuming that more current = more gravity force, and that these forces are somewhat reasonable.

The first disaster that comes to mind:

**Modern society never develops.**

In the most drastic case, the primitive tribe of apes that eventually become humans are a little too close to some of this mineral when a lightning strike happens and are all sucked into a temporary gravitational well and mooshed into a sticky paste. Alternatively, the various tribes and societies throughout history have more concrete proof of the warring gods, as swaths of land are rearranged and villages disappear after thunderstorms. Or even just the objects inside the hut all fly to one side. This can cause drastic effects as it becomes much harder to take a scientific approach to discovery when obviously it’s the witch down the street or the gods having marriage counseling.

**Modern society starts to develop: Not much happens!**

Discounting the above scenario; starting out, unless this mineral has other interesting properties that make it of use to humans, the mineral won’t be used. Even after humans start playing with electricity, it might not be discovered right away, and even then, would probably be considered more of a curiosity. I don’t believe you would get “airships” that make use of it because of the amount of extra weight electricity-generating and -storing equipment will have vs just having more fuel. Man-made disasters with this mineral won’t start to happen until they get to the point of massive power generation, at which point you’ll have a few people implode their laboratories and maybe their universities/power-plants before they learn it’s a “Bad Thing.”

You won’t see these used as weapons much for the same reason as the fuel for airships one; it’s easier to pack more explosives in something than generate the same amount of electricity.

**Shrinking planet:**

Then again, if this stuff is everywhere, and there is SOME current it is picking up, it is producing gravity. Maybe it’s getting some bleed off from the polar magnetic field, or something with solar flares; but the extra gravity over time is telling. The moon could grow closer, and all the damage THAT causes. It could pull asteroids that would have otherwise missed the planet in closer, which also is pretty bad of an outcome. If more of this mineral was on one continent than another it could pull that landmass apart, rearranging the planet in the process (this wouldn’t be that fast of a process however.) The extra pulling pressure could result in more pressure being applied to the planets core, but the effects of that are beyond my knowledge.

As far as disasters concerning this mineral, outside of lightning strikes or similar, you’re not going to get much small scale going on. Most of the rest of it is going to be world-ending stuff if it ever happens.